# Tracing all possible states of program WITHOUT explicit variable declaration in Python

Tags: python, performance, unit-testing, time, trace

My goal is to find a Python tracing function that will trace all possible states of a program WITHOUT defining variables beforehand; variable/argument definitions need to be done within the tracing function in an iterative manner based on the program.

Below examples will use python's [trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module as this is the closest I've come.

**A simple example**

Using the trace module, we can build easily trace the states of a program. For example, if we define our variables (`condition_A`, `condition_B`, and `condition_C`) in a sample program which decided what to print based on the state of each of those variables (either `True` or `False` here), then tracing is easy. In one file we have the following:

```py
#filname - simple_example.py
import random

condition_A = random.choice((True, False))
condition_B = random.choice((True, False))
condition_C = random.choice((True, False))

def func_A_True():
    print("func_A_True")
def func_A_False():
    print("func_A_False")

def func_B_True():
    print("func_B_True")
def func_B_False():
    print("func_B_False")

def func_C_True():
    print("func_C_True")
def func_C_False():
    print("func_C_False")

def decision_func_A():
    if condition_A:
        func_A_True()
    else:
        func_A_False()

def decision_func_B():
    if condition_B:
        func_B_True()
    else:
        func_B_False()

def decision_func_C():
    if condition_C:
        func_C_True()
    else:
        func_C_False()

def main():
    decision_func_A()
    decision_func_B()
    decision_func_C()
```

And when we trace this code via another file, we get expected output as per the trace module:

```
#filename - tracer_simple_example.py
from simple_example import main
import trace

tracer = trace.Trace(count=False, trace=True)
tracer.run('main()')

#---------------------------------------------Output---------------------------
# --- modulename: tracer_simple_example, funcname: <module>
#<string>(1):  --- modulename: simple_example, funcname: main
#simple_example.py(41):     decision_func_A()
# --- modulename: simple_example, funcname: decision_func_A
#simple_example.py(23):     if condition_A:
#simple_example.py(24):         func_A_True()
# --- modulename: simple_example, funcname: func_A_True
#simple_example.py(8):  print("func_A_True")
#func_A_True
#simple_example.py(42):     decision_func_B()
# --- modulename: simple_example, funcname: decision_func_B
#simple_example.py(29):     if condition_B:
#simple_example.py(32):         func_B_False()
# --- modulename: simple_example, funcname: func_B_False
#simple_example.py(15):     print("func_B_False")
#func_B_False
#simple_example.py(43):     decision_func_C()
# --- modulename: simple_example, funcname: decision_func_C
#simple_example.py(35):     if condition_C:
#simple_example.py(36):         func_C_True()
# --- modulename: simple_example, funcname: func_C_True
#simple_example.py(18):     print("func_C_True")
#func_C_True
```

**Problem 1: Variables can take different values**

What if we alter the above example such that our conditions can take a range of possible states. So in this case instead of picking a specific condition in advance, the `condition` variables are iterable with a range of possible values. So in the above example we only change the variables declaration

```
#filename - func_to_trace.py
condition_A = (True, False)
condition_B = (True, False)
condition_C = (True, False)
```

Now running the same tracing script (filename - tracer.py) produces meaningless ouput as it only tells me that I have declated the decision functions but never actionally executes the printing functions.

Instead, the desired output would be this:

```
Vartion 1: Main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_True -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_True -> print -> decision_func_C -> func_C_True -> print
Vartion 2: Main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_True -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_True -> print -> decision_func_C -> func_C_False -> print
Vartion 3: Main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_True -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_False -> print -> decision_func_C -> func_C_True -> print
Vartion 4: Main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_True -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_False -> print -> decision_func_C -> func_C_False -> print
Vartion 5: Main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_False -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_True -> print -> decision_func_C -> func_C_True -> print
Vartion 6: Main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_False -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_True -> print -> decision_func_C -> func_C_False -> print
Vartion 7: Main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_False -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_False -> print -> decision_func_C -> func_C_True -> print
Vartion 8: Main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_False -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_False -> print -> decision_func_C -> func_C_False -> print
```

(i.e. `condition_A`, `condition_B` and `condition_C` would be varied: `(True, True, True), (True, True, False), (True, False, True), (True, False, False), (False, True, True), (False, True, False), (False, False, True), (False, False, False)`)

**Problem 2: Non-boolean values**

The above example might seem deceptively simple. In the above case, the conditions were DEFINITELy either met or not in their respective decision function. We can change that and we can also use strings. For example:

```
#filename - func_to_trace_example2.py
string_A = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
string_B = ("a", "b", "c", "d")

def func_A_a():
    print("func_A_a")
def func_A_b():
    print("func_A_b")

def func_B_c():
    print("func_B_c")
def func_B_d():
    print("func_B_d")

def decision_func_A():
    if string_A == "a":
        func_A_a()
    elif string_A == "b":
        func_A_b()

def decision_func_B():
    if string_B == "c":
        func_B_c()
    elif string_B == "d":
        func_B_d()

def main():
    decision_func_A()
    decision_func_B()
```

Tracing (filename - tracer_example2.py) this also produces the same meaningless output as it cannot iterate through the values as I want. So, the desired tracing function would search the code for where variables are declared and iterate (if possible) with each possibility; if variables are declared multiple times, try all values.

The desired output here would be:

```
Variation 1 [string_A = a, string_B = a]: main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_a -> print -> decision_func_B [Note that it does not continue after decision_func_B]
Variation 2 [string_A = a, string_B = b]: main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_a -> print -> decision_func_B
Variation 3 [string_A = a, string_B = c]: main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_a -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_c -> print
Variation 4 [string_A = a, string_B = d]: main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_a -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_d -> print
Variation 5 [string_A = b, string_B = a]: main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_b -> print -> decision_func_B
Variation 6 [string_A = b, string_B = b]: main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_b -> print -> decision_func_B
Variation 7 [string_A = b, string_B = c]: main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_b -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_c -> print
Variation 8 [string_A = b, string_B = d]: main -> decision_func_A -> func_A_b -> print -> decision_func_B -> func_B_d -> print
Variation 9 [string_A = c, string_B = a]: main -> decision_func_A -> decision_func_B
Variation 10 [string_A = c, string_B = b]: main -> decision_func_A -> decision_func_B
Variation 11 [string_A = c, string_B = c]: main -> decision_func_A -> decision_func_B -> func_B_c -> print
Variation 12 [string_A = c, string_B = d]: main -> decision_func_A -> decision_func_B -> func_B_d -> print
Variation 13 [string_A = d, string_B = a]: main -> decision_func_A -> decision_func_B
Variation 14 [string_A = d, string_B = b]: main -> decision_func_A -> decision_func_B
Variation 15 [string_A = d, string_B = c]: main -> decision_func_A -> decision_func_B -> func_B_c -> print
Variation 16 [string_A = d, string_B = d]: main -> decision_func_A -> decision_func_B -> func_B_d -> print
```

**Problem 3: Scaling the desired tracing function**

Scaling might pose challenges on its own but the central idea - it seems to me - is to be able to run functions and if an argument is required for a function or a variable for a condition, then check the code, search all declarations of that argument/variable and iterate through them. So, to give an example for a user interface - where this sort of this is like to be most useful - we can build a simple app:

```
#filename - func_to_trace_example_gui.py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def print_A():
    print("choice is a")
def print_B():
    print("choice is b")
def print_C():
    print("choice is c")

def decision_func_master(choice):
    if choice == "a":
        print_A()
    elif choice == "b":
        print_B()
    elif choice == "c":
        print_C()

#building the app
master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Tracing example")
master.geometry("250x150")

#declaring a variable within the UI
combobox_var_tk = tk.StringVar()

#creating a dropdown combobox with a list of options
combobox_options = ("a", "b", "c")
cb = ttk.Combobox(master, values=combobox_options, state="readonly", width=30, textvariable=combobox_var_tk)
cb.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=15)

#on-submit function
def submit():
    #combobox_var_master = combobox_var_tk.get() #e.g. comobobox_var_2 is going to be used by a lot of subsequent functions and it's awkward to call .get() every time
    decision_func_master(combobox_var_tk.get())

#submit button
ttk.Button(master, text="GO!", command=submit).grid(row=1, column=0)

#run the UI
if __name__ == "__main__":
    master.mainloop()
```

The tracing script (filename - func_to_trace_example_gui.py) applied to the submit function again is meaningless as it does not take any values for variables.

In this case, however, what should happen is that submit function should get executed, then the get function to get the variable declared in the UI and then we should be able to find that the `textvariable` of the combobox can be set by one of the `values` from `combobox_options` and hence iterate through those. This can get complicated if the `state` is not `readonly` but, if we do have such a case where a value for a variable is need but we have not defined, then either raise an error or take any random value.

So for this case the desired output would be:

```
Variation 1 [combobox choice is a]: submit -> get -> decision_func_master -> print_A
Variation 2 [combobox choice is b]: submit -> get -> decision_func_master -> print_B
Variation 3 [combobox choice is c]: submit -> get -> decision_func_master -> print_C
```

---

**Why do I need that**

Possible use cases include unit testing as I can quickly take all possible states of my program. This might also be useful in debugging as I will be able to see the values of variables in all states of my program. Another way this can be useful is to simply time the execution of all possible states of the program.

---

**Files**

An archive of all files needed to reproduce the above examples, can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PIx25uTTAX62p0nxThjcgXHUaK2cug9p/view?usp=sharing). Filenames of each example are given in the text above.

Comment: I really like this idea as I imagine it could be very useful to run a program and then save the input and output state from each function for use as a unit test. I could even imagine the user selecting or "correcting" the return state to what they think it should be..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @BrendanCody-Kenny. I still haven't found a solution short of developing an entire framework. I have co-developed a functionality along those lines for a specific JavaScript-based framework, wherein we have a 'simulation' mode, which mimics the behaviour of a user (although in that case the possible behaviours are VERY constrained AND the simulation mode is framework-specific) (see [here](https://www.jspsych.org/7.1/overview/simulation/)). A general-purpose solution still seems to be lacking.

Comment: I recently used [dill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63675143/using-dill-to-save-current-state-of-jupyter-notebook) to save and restore the entire state of a jupyter notebook, you might find simple code in there that iterates over all state objects. I'm thinking the PDB debugger or [trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63675143/using-dill-to-save-current-state-of-jupyter-notebook) might also be useful for what you want.